# Parsing json data not showing correct value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=350&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
    NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

    NSDictionary *dictOne = [results objectAtIndex:0];

    appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *activitiesArray = [dictOne objectForKey:@"events"];



    NSDictionary *dictTwo = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *eventArray=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"event"];
    NSDictionary *dictThree=[eventArray objectAtIndex:0];



//  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictOne objectForKey:@"date"]);

//  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"]);


    NSString*date=[dictOne objectForKey:@"date"];

    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"]);
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictThree objectForKey:@"title"]);
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictThree objectForKey:@"location"]);
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictThree objectForKey:@"municipality"]);
```

when i NSLog(title) location and municipality it shows nil values

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "date": 1311552000000,
    "events": [
      {
        "affectedDate": 1311552000000,
        "event": {
          "appId": 42,
          "eventId": 18095,
          "location": "Sjølingstad Uldvarefabrik",
          "municipality": "Lindesnes",
          "title": "Utstillingsåpning - romfisk"
        }
      },
      {
        "affectedDate": 1311552000000,
        "event": {
          "appId": 42,
          "eventId": 18095,
          "location": "Sjølingstad Uldvarefabrik",
          "municipality": "Lindesnes",
          "title": "Utstillingsåpning - romfisk"
        }
      },
      {
        "affectedDate": 1311580800000,
        "event": {
          "appId": 620,
          "eventId": 19490,
          "location": "Høvåg Gjestehus, Vestre Vallesverd, Høvåg",
          "municipality": "Lillesand",
          "title": "Kunstutstilling på Høvåg Gjestehus"
        }
      },
...
]
```

Following Praveen answer I have tried this code but it's still not working:

```
NSDictionary *dictOne = [results objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *activitiesArray = [dictOne objectForKey:@"events"];
NSDictionary *dictTwo = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSArray *eventArray=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"event"];
NSDictionary *dictThree=[eventArray objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: Pls, provide the json, so we know how it's structured.

Comment: http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=350&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder

Comment: this is the json data which i am using

Comment: Please edit your own questions with updates, not someone else answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to initialize the parser, b/c SBJSON uses NSString category to add additional parsing method to standard NSString called `JSONValue` that returns `NSDictionary` representation of a `NSString`.

After you get a NSDictionary, convert it to NSArray like this `NSArray * values = [dictionary allValues];` then use method `[values objectForKey:@"date"]` to get a date and so on.

Comment: i am using like this as you have seen in code its showign date affecteddate but not showing other values

Answer (score 0):

Its nested Json. The parsing and retrieval of values are different. Once you get the the dictionary value for a nested object you need to dig into it for getting the next values.

1. From the main array getobject for events.
2. Get object for event from the above Dictionary
3. From the dictionary returned in step 2 you can access appId, eventId etc

So basically your code should be

```
NSDictionary *dictTwo = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:1]; // Or get object for key events
```